LAMP Webserver using Raspberry Pi 4, Wordpress, and Apache
I'm trying to follow a tutorial to get wordpress on raspberry pi to make a webserver on it (bottom of page) and when I do:
'sudo apt-get install apache2 -y'

I get the following output:
'Err:1 http:// raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian bullseye/main armhf apache2-bin armhf 2.4.56-    1~deb11u2
404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err:2 http:// raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian bullseye/main armhf apache2-data all 2.4.56-1~deb11u2
404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err:3 http:// raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian bullseye/main armhf apache2-utils armhf 2.4.56-1~deb11u2
404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err:4 http:// raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian bullseye/main armhf apache2 armhf 2.4.56-1~deb11u2
404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http:// raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2-bin_2.4.56-1%7edeb11u2_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://
raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2-data_2.4.56-1%7edeb11u2_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http:// raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2-utils_2.4.56-1%7edeb11u2_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http:// raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2_2.4.56-1%7edeb11u2_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?'
How do I resolve this? I have Raspbian Legacy 32bit OS, Raspberry Pi4
Ive tried:
'apt-get install -f --reinstall apache2'

same error
'apt-get remove --purge -s apache2'

successful then I tried this again
'apt-get install apache2'

same error
tutorial: https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/lamp-web-server-with-wordpress/2

When I browse to http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian%20bullseye/ with a web-browser, I get error 404 too. It looks like some of your output says http;//  (note the trailing space) rather than http:// but that's not going to help matters.
